# PHP : onkeyup input text

Tags: javascript

I use the onkeyup function and the result as in the picture

[image]

```
        function DES1(val){
            var a = document.getElementById(val.id).value
            var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".des1");
            for(var i=0;i < inputs.length;i++)
            {
               inputs[i].value = a;
            }
        }

<label>A</label><font color="red">*</font>
<input type="text" name="id" id="des1" onkeyup="DES1(this)">
<label>B</label><font color="red">*</font>
<input type="text" class="des1">
```

but when I type the number 3 (then comes the history figure of the form)
[image]

when I click the number and fill in the input, but the input B does not follow the input A, how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: You can use onChange event.

Comment: can you please describe your goal? what is the result you want?

Comment: `autocomplete='off'` should avoid that behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onkeyup` should be used if you want to bind a function when user releases a key and `oninput` should be used if there is a change in value of input. You should use `oninput`. Try this:

```js
function DES1(val){
    var a = document.getElementById(val.id).value
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".des1");
    for(var i=0;i < inputs.length;i++) {
       inputs[i].value = a;
    }
}
```

```html
<label>A</label><font color="red">*</font>
<input type="text" name="id" id="des1" oninput="DES1(this)">
<label>B</label><font color="red">*</font>
<input type="text" class="des1">
```

Comment: @illogic Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You neeed [onchange event](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

```js
$("#des1").change(function(){
  var value = $("#des1").val();
  $(".des1").val(value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>A</label><font color="red">*</font>
<input type="text" name="id" id="des1">
<label>B</label><font color="red">*</font>
<input type="text" class="des1">
```

When You are using onkeyup event it does not identify when use copies text from somewhere or select from autocomplete. but on-change event works whenever the input is change.

Comment: *when I click the number and fill in the input, but the input B does not follow the input A*

Comment: Thanks . Updated..!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see a jQuery tag.